# Replace Part of String with a different String in QGIS using Python

Tags: pyqgis, expression, qgis-custom-function

I am trying to fix a field that has Street Names. Some of the features' Street Names have abbreviation rather than the full name of the type of street like for example 'PRESTON LAKE DR' when it should be 'PRESTON LAKE DRIVE'

[image]

I have a dictionary to replace all those abbreviations:

{'RD': 'ROAD',
                    'CIR': 'CIRCLE',
                    'DR': 'DRIVE',
                    'LN': 'LANE',
                    'CT': 'COURT',
                    'PL': 'PLACE',
                    'ST': 'STREET',
                    'BLVD': 'BOULEVARD'}

I am looking for a way to elegantly replace all these abbreviations with their corresponding full name using Python.

I am new to Python and QGIS and would like to get a detailed answer and preferably with Sample Code.

Comment: Split the string (on spaces) and take the last 'word'.  If this 'word' (eg, "DR") is in the dictionary (as a key), then join all the other 'words' with the dictionary value for that key, (join using a space).

Comment: Thanks. I am very new to Python and QGIS, so would prefer a detailed answer, maybe with example.

Comment: You have all the pieces you need.  No one is going to write your code for you, especially when you haven't provided any code of your own.  Start with the [developer cookbook for pyqgis](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/) and [python dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), if you haven't already.  If you have attempted to write some code and you're stuck, please provide a sample and indicate where you're stuck.

Comment: Also, evaluate whether you need a full script.  You can probably achieve your goal using a field calculator expression.

Comment: @jbalk thanks. I was able finding it hard to get a start, a colleague helped me and I was able to put it together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure this out with the help of a colleague. Here is the code:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def street_name_fix(StreetName, feature, parent):
    replacements = {'RD': 'ROAD',
                    'CIR': 'CIRCLE',
                    'DR': 'DRIVE',
                    'LN': 'LANE',
                    'CT': 'COURT',
                    'PL': 'PLACE',
                    'ST': 'STREET',
                    'BLVD': 'BOULEVARD'}

    StreetName = StreetName.upper().strip().rstrip('.')

    try:
        return '{} {}'.format(' '.join(StreetName.split()[:-1]), replacements[StreetName.split()[-1]])

    except IndexError:
        return StreetName

    except KeyError:
        return StreetName
```

Comment: You should pull your `replacements = ` dictionary out of the function.  Having it in the function means it gets redefined every time that function is called (probably once for every record/feature that you process) which is very inefficient.  Define it separately, eg, as a global to make your code more efficient (and arguably more readable).

Comment: Looks good but names like 'Some St E' or 'Persons Name St' aren't handled adequately, try iterating over the components (start with newName = []), for x in StreetName.split() then if x in replacements replace with replacements[x] then append x to newName (newName.append(x)) and finally return ' '.join(newName) which will replace any succinct instance of replacement with the full but not parts of words (like 'BARD RD' => 'BARD ROAD' and not 'BAROAD ROAD') - unfortunately a street called 'ST MARY DR' will become 'STREET MARY DRIVE' and not 'SAINT MARY DRIVE'... but you can't win 'em all.